# Any downsides to approximating content-length header?

Tags: http, http-headers

I'm creating zip files on the fly for download, I don't know how big they are going to turn out exactly but I can give a pretty good guess. I added it for the sake of client side fluff since the downloads are pretty big but having a progress bar isn't essential. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2 says Content-Length is for "anticipated size" which can be interpreted as either exact or approximate.

So far all the browsers I've tried don't have a problem with an approximate content size header but are there any out there that do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read it completely!

If you are using HTTP/1.1, and do not use chunked encoding, the content-length absolutely needs to be precise; it's needed for the message framing.